# Mix ecto.create filling with insufficient privileges error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Received this error after trying to run `mix ecto.create`:

> ** (Mix) The database for Rumbl.Repo couldn't be created: ERROR 42501 (insufficient_privilege): permission denied to create database

Anyone knows what I should do?

Answer (score 4):

You should grant for role you are using (username field in the config/dev.exs)  [Postgresql privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alteruser.html) for creating db, so you should run:

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
```

and then, when you are logging as superuser

```
postgres=# ALTER USER your_username WITH CREATEDB;
```

Then logout `\q` and restart your Postresql server

```
$ sudo service postgresql restart
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolved this by changing the username field in the config/dev.exs from postgres to my user name.

Answer (score -2):

Run =>  sudo -u postgres psql

postgres=# ALTER ROLE your_role_name CREATEDB;

ALTER ROLE

postgres=# Create DB

postgres-# \q